# Intuition: Limit of homogeneous rational functions at zero is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider two real valued polynomials $p(x,y)$ and $q(x,y)$ where $p,q$ are homogeneous and degree of $p$ is greater than degree of $q$.Intuitively it looks like $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}=0$$
Is my intuition correct? I tried to prove it but didn't succeed.

**My approach**:I convert x and y into polar coordinates and then observe that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}=\lim_{r\to 0}r^k\frac{f(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)}{g(\sin\theta,\cos\theta))}$$
Where $\theta$ is variable (depending on path) and k=degree of p-degree of q.

The problem may arise if f/g becomes an indeterminate form,hence I didn't complete my proof.In case if $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{f(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)}{g(\sin\theta,\cos\theta))}$ goes to infinity then $\lim_{r\to 0}r^k\frac{f(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)}{g(\sin\theta,\cos\theta))}$ may not be zero
If my intuition is not correct then please give counter example,further when can we say that limit is zero?

Comment: Consider $(x,y) \mapsto x^2/y$ and show that the limit at $0$ does not exist by using the sequence $x_n=1/n$, $y_n =1/n^3$.

Comment: Nice example!what about my second question,i.e when is result true?

Comment: @marktmeiser is the $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}xy\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}=0$?